# Heartbeat value configuration for RabbitMQ

Tags: queue, message-queuing, rabbitmq

I have RabbitMQ set up on a Debian server.  I find myself in a situation currently whereby I need to change (or perhaps enable?) the heartbeat value for RabbitMQ.  I have not been able to find any examples of how to do this via the /etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config file.  I took a guess of the following, which does not work:

```
[{rabbit,
    [{heartbeat, 30}]
}].
```

Does anybody know how to properly configure the heartbeat value for RabbitMQ?  I'm using version 1.7.1.

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of RabbitMQ?  The current version is 2.7.1 and is available as a .deb http://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html

Comment: This was over a year ago.  :P  We've since moved over to 0MQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I suspected, the heartbeat is solely configured client-side.  This was confirmed in #rabbitmq on Freenode IRC.  The particular issues I'm having with heartbeats are related to the client-side library that I'm using.

Comment: Are you sure? It would seem is possible to change the default value by configuration: https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html (search for heartbeat there)

Answer (score 2):

The information in the answer is no longer correct.

RabbitMQ now has configurable setting for heartbeat both from client and from the server.

The lower value is taken during connection negotiation, by default the server uses 60 seconds.
They can also be disabled by setting both client and server to 0.

More info can be found here:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html